DejaDup can't restore after fresh install, searches forever
Last week I backed up everything using Backups (DejaDup), then I swapped the old SSD for a new one and did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04.
I've installed DejaDup and Duplicity. I just get a never ending screen showing "Scanning backup files..."
I've searched for solutions, and I've tried setting the Backup location as Local folder and specifying the folder (I've also tried setting it as the specific external HD). I've checked the permissions of the backup files (I am the owner).
I'd be very grateful for any help or suggestions.
Thanks
Henry

How come my question has been voted down? I'm really interested in how I can make the question clearer or more relevant. I've spent a couple of hours searching for solutions and trying different options and I mention this in my question. I'm a farmer, not an IT professional, so maybe I don't know the right language to use, but I've been using Ubuntu since 2005 and this is a serious question for me and I need help please.

It looks like someone is downvoting every new question; don't let it bother you. When your external drive containing the backup is plugged in to your system, what are the permissions and owner on its mount point? It's probably called something like /media/your-user-name/a-lot-of-numbers. And, can you browse the backup directory with the file manager?

Thanks @OrganicMarble. It's /media/henry/Adata HD700 I'm the owner. I have read and write permissions, and I can browse all the folders including the backup folder

That all sounds proper on the backup mount. I may have experienced a similar problem a while back, I'll check my installation notes.

@OrganicMarble Most of the files on the backup drive are backups, but I have found some documents I can open with LibreOffice, however even though I recently installed vlc on my new system, I can't launch it at all. There are also some other system glitches that I assume will be addressed in the update cycle - my new system is struggling with Settings (flickering windows) and if I right click in Files the menu flickers too. Both of these can cause the whole system to hang, requiring a hard reboot, but until I found the problem with vlc I just thought it was a window rendering issue.

@OrganicMarble It seems like I should ask the community another question, so I have done here
